# _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass symbol(s) not found error, but library seems to be linked

Tags: objective-c, linker, ld

I'm getting error "Undefined symbols: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", even though the library that defines MyClass *seems* to be linked.

The Xcode project builds fine on my computer but gets the error on another computer (same OS X, same Xcode, same GCC). However, none of the paths in the `ld` command are specific to my computer.

The `ld` command contains `-L/path/to/DirectoryOfMyLibrary` and `-lMyLibrary`.

The library contains the required architecture (x86_64).

```
$ file libMyLibrary.a
libMyLibrary.a: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture x86_64):   current ar archive random library
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture i386): current ar archive random library
libMyLibrary.a (for architecture ppc):  current ar archive random library
```

Build Setting "Symbols hidden by default" is NOT checked on the library. The symbol is in the library.

```
$ nm libMyLibrary.a | grep MyClass
0000000000002370 S _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass
```

I read through a bunch of similar questions but did not find this exact problem. Any ideas?

**Edit**:

The project builds on a third computer, so it looks like the problem is specific to one computer; it's not the project per se.

I think that implies that `/path/to/DirectoryOfMyLibrary` is correct.

Tried cleaning, did not help.

Comment: Did you import a .m file rather than the .h in your class? Doing so causes some vague errors like this. EDIT: Didn't notice you said it builds fine on another system, likely not the problem then.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the target?

Comment: You've verified that `/path/to/DirectoryOfMyLibrary` is valid and correct on both machines, and that the Location popup ("Absolute Path"/"Relative to Group"/"Relative to Project" and so on) is the same?